# Infinitely many positive integers $m$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a_n = \left[\sqrt{(n+1)^2+n^2}\right], n = 1,2,\ldots,$ where $[x]$ denotes the integer part of $x$. Prove that
>
> $\quad$ (a) there are infinitely many positive integers $m$ such that $a_{m+1}-a_{m} > 1$;
>
> $\quad$ (b) there are infinitely many positive integers $m$ such that $a_{m+1}-a_m = 1$.

If $a_{m+1} \geq a_m+1$, then if $k^2 \leq 2m^2+2m+1 < (k+1)^2 \implies k < 2m$, then $$(k+1)^2 \leq 4m^2.$$

How can we continue this approach or is there another way (I saw another way using Pell equations)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A famous fact about binomial coefficients is:
$$\binom{n}{2}\text{ is a perfect square for infinitely many } n.$$
This statement can be proved without Pell's equation, in the following way:
$$\binom{(2n-1)^2}{2}=(2n-1)^2\cdot2n(n-1)$$
and if $\binom{n}{2}$ is a perfect square, the above expression is another perfect square. Now note that $\binom{9}{2}=6^2$.

Thus we may take $m=n-2$ where $\binom{n}{2}$ is a perfect square and finish the proof of (a).
(b) is trivial.

Comment: How does this prove part (a)?

Comment: @user19405892 Suppose $n(n-1)=2k^2$. One may immediately check that $a_{n-1}=2k$ and $a_{n-2}\leq 2k-2$(This inequality is done by a plain estimation $n>k+1$).

Comment: Can you explain how to get $a_{n-2} \leq 2k-2$? How do you know $n > k+1$?

Comment: If $n\leq k+1$ then $n(n-1)\leq k(k+1)<2k^2$, a contrdiction. So $\sqrt{(n-1)^2+(n-2)^2}=\sqrt{2n(n-1)-4n+5}<\sqrt{4k^2-4(k+1)+5}=2k-1$.

Comment: How do we prove (b)?

Comment: (b) can be answered in a lot of ways. For example, just take $m=n-1$.

Comment: We get $a_{n-1} = 2k$. How do you find $a_n = 2k+1$?

Comment: It's just the same technique. We may say $k+1<n<\sqrt{2}k+1$ and estimate $a_n$.

Comment: Can you explain how to estimate $a_n$?

Comment: $\sqrt{(n+1)^2+n^2+1}=\sqrt{2n(n-1)+4n+2}=\sqrt{4k^2+4n+2}$, which is greater than $\sqrt{4k^2+4(k+1)+2}>2k+1$ but less than $\sqrt{4k^2+4(\sqrt{2}k+1)+2}<\sqrt{4k^2+8k+4}=2k+2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof sketch.  First we show that $a_{m+1} - a_m$ can never be zero.  This is because $(n+1)^2 + n^2$ increases by $4n + 4$ when $n$ increases by $1$.  But, consecutive squares near $(n+1)^2 + n^2$ are closer together than this.  (They are roughly $2 \sqrt{2} n$ apart).  So $\sqrt{(n+2)^2 + (n+1)^2}$ and $\sqrt{(n+1)^2 + n^2}$ differ by more than one, and their floors cannot be the same.

Next, assume (a) is false.  There are only finitely many $m$ such that $a_{m+1} - a_m > 1$, so let $n$ be the largest one.  For any $m > n$, $a_{m+1} = a_m + 1$.  This means, for instance, $a_{2n} - a_n = n$.  But the difference between $\sqrt{(n+1)^2 + n^2}$ and $\sqrt{(2n + 1)^2 + (2n)^2}$ is roughly $n\sqrt{2}$; it is too big for the difference of the floors to be $n$.

Similarly, assume (b) is false.  Now we can say for any $m > n$, $a_{m+1} \ge a_m + 2$.  So $a_{2n} - a_n \ge 2n$.  The difference of floors of square roots cannot be this large when the difference of square roots directly is, as above, roughly $n\sqrt{2}$.